# Using SimpleXML to extract data from XML page returning empty array

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm trying to extract the values of all elements named wardtitle from this xml page:
https://democracy.ashfield-dc.gov.uk/mgWebService.asmx/GetCouncillorsByWard

Here's the code I'm currently trying:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("https://democracy.ashfield-dc.gov.uk/mgWebService.asmx/GetCouncillorsByWard");
var_dump($xml->children());

$ward = (string) $xml->wardtitle;
echo $ward;

print_r($xml->xpath("//email"));
```

The children dump seems to work fine, the $ward variable returns nothing, then the xpath attempt returns the correct number of results, but all empty...
Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to xml structure: `wardtitle` is a node of each `ward`, which in turn - node of `wards`, so, to echo `wardtitle` of **first** ward:

```
echo $xml->wards->ward[0]->wardtitle;
```

As for emails - everything works fine:

```
foreach ($xml->xpath("//email") as $email) {
    echo $email;
}
```